# DHCP request message and client's MAC Addr

Tags: networking, dhcp

Does DHCP request message have to include the client's MAC address? If so, can someone explain why?

Comment: It is the only identifier of the network interface.

Answer (score 0):

A DHCP request is specifically a 2 way process: the client machine sends out its MAC ID in the DHCP Discovery process.  So no, you can't do a conventional DHCP connection without handing out a MAC ID.

The discovery packet set contains the CHADDR, whic is set to the MAC address used by the client.

It is theoretically possible to spoof a different MAC ID, if you do not want to use your actual chipset's MAC ID

http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Spoof-Your-MAC-Address/

Note that this is generally frowned upon, and may violate policies or laws, depending on where you live & work.....